# Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "List[<nothing>]", variable has type (...)

Tags: python, mypy

Consider the following self-contained example:

```
from typing import List, Union

T_BENCODED_LIST = Union[List[bytes], List[List[bytes]]]
ret: T_BENCODED_LIST = []
```

When I test it with mypy, I get the following error:

```
example.py:4: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "List[<nothing>]", variable has type "Union[List[bytes], List[List[bytes]]]")
```

What is the problem here and how can I properly annotate this example?

Comment: Related issue on GitHub: [No type inference for dicts in union](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6463)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is related to the following mypy bugs:

- https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2164
- https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6463

The issue relates to the use of `Union` with an empty list.

There are two ways to deal with this:

1. Get mypy to ignore the empty list assignment (not ideal, but probably the simplest approach)
2. Use a type-hinted function to perform the empty list assignment

### Approach 1 - Get mypy to ignore the empty list assignment

```py
from typing import List, Union

# Define the variable with type hint
T_BENCODED_LIST: Union[List[bytes], List[List[bytes]]]

# Set the value to empty list and tell mypy to look the other way.
T_BENCODED_LIST = []  # type: ignore
```

This feels like a reasonable approach, because it allows mypy to continue to assume that the type is correctly defined.

### Approach 2 - Use a type-hinted function for empty list assignment

Using a type-hinted function avoids the issue with `Union` and empty lists. This approach means adding code that is only necessary for working around the typing issue, so isn't my preferred approach.

```py
from typing import List, Union

# Define the variable with type hint
T_BENCODED_LIST: Union[List[bytes], List[List[bytes]]]

# Create a type-hinted function that can be used
# for assignment.
def get_empty_list_bytes() -> List[bytes]:
    return []

# Set the value to empty list using the function.
# Mypy will assume the type based on the functions type hint.
T_BENCODED_LIST = get_empty_list_bytes()
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, however trying first approach doesn't solve the linter issue as now it's angry that the list is empty: 
```error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "List[<nothing>]", variable has type "List[str]")  [assignment]``` (2023)

Comment: @Eve, interesting - that means the `type: ignore` isn't doing what it's supposed to do. I've not had that before. Is that from an IDE or from mypy?

Comment: I was running with mypy 0.991 and python 3.7, i'm not using the VScode extension. It's a bit weird because it does seem to ignore the specific line but then it fails downstream checks.