# mypy error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Dict[<nothing>, <nothing>]", target has type "List[str]")

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I tried to *instantiate an empty dictionary* on the second level of an existing dict, then assign a key-value pair to it, but MyPy throws an error.

Here is a minimal example, which will reproduce it when MyPy checking is activated:

```
result = {"Test": "something"}
result['key'] = {}
result['key']['sub_key'] = ["some string", "another string"]
```

The error here will be something like:

```
mypy(error): Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type
"Dict[<nothing>, <nothing>]", target has type "List[str]")
```

How do I prevent this error?
According to a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58906541/incompatible-types-in-assignment-expression-has-type-listnothing-variabl), it was suggested to do

```
result['key'] = {}  # type: ignore
```

as a workaround, but this does not seem very elegant, which is why I'm wondering if there is more one can do.

Comment: In https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10 I see `Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Dict[<nothing>, <nothing>]", target has type "str")` - you'd get `List[str]` if the initial definition was e.g. `{"Test": ["something"]}`. What do _you think_ the type of `result` should be? Have you tried being explicit about that when defining it?

Comment: Thanks for your hints, according to @Alex Waygood's answer below, one should declare the variable types even when they are created within the function.

Comment: You have to declare them explicitly if the inferred type (based on the value you initially assigned) isn't actually what you intend, yes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

##### The problem

Right, so let's look at the first two lines here.

First, you define your dictionary `result`. You define it like so:

```
result = {"Test": "something"}
```

You don't declare what types you expect the keys and values of `result` to have, so MyPy is left to work it out for itself. Alright, it says, I can do this — you've got only strings as dictionary keys, and only strings as dictionary values, therefore `result` must be of type `dict[str, str]`.

Then we get to line 2:

```
result['key'] = {}
```

And MyPy, quite reasonably, raises an error. "Hey, this looks like a mistake!" it says. You've only got strings as dictionary values in this so far, and you haven't explicitly told MyPy that it's okay to have non-`str` values in this dictionary, so MyPy reckons you've probably made an error here, and didn't mean to add that value to the dictionary.

No real need to look at the third line, because it's basically the same thing going on

##### How to fix this?

There are a couple of ways of fixing this. In order of most-preferred (use if possible) to least-preferred (use only as a last resort):

1. You can tell MyPy that *this specific* dictionary has certain types associated with certain string-keys by annotating it as a `TypedDict`. (You'll have to change your `"sub-key"` key to `"sub_key"`, however, as "sub-key" isn't a valid variable name.)

   ```
   from typing import TypedDict

   class KeyDict(TypedDict, total=False):
       sub_key: list[str]


   class ResultDict(TypedDict, total=False):
       Test: str
       key: KeyDict


   result: ResultDict = {"Test": "something"}
   result['key'] = {}
   result['key']['sub_key'] = ["some string", "another string"]
   ```
2. You can tell MyPy that *any* value in this dictionary could be of type `str`, or it could be of type `dict[str, list[str]]`:

   ```
   from typing import Union

   result: dict[str, Union[str, dict[str, list[str]]]] = {"Test": "something"}
   d: dict[str, list[str]] = {}
   d['sub_key'] = ["some string", "another string"]
   result['key'] = d
   ```
3. You can tell MyPy that the value in this dictionary could be *anything* (not that different from switching off the type-checker):

   ```
   from typing import Any

   result: dict[str, Any] = {"Test": "something"}
   result['key'] = {}
   result['key']['sub_key'] = ["some string", "another string"]
   ```
4. You can switch off the type-checker:

   ```
   result = {"Test": "something"}  
   result['key'] = {}  # type: ignore[assignment]
   result['key']['sub_key'] = ["some string", "another string"] # type: ignore[index]
   ```

Anyway, it's a bit difficult to know what the "best" solution is here without knowing more about your use case.