# Why does mypy have a hard time with assignment to nested dicts?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

`mypy` version 0.910

Consider

```
d = {
    'a': 'a',
    'b': {
        'c': 1
    }
}

d['b']['d'] = 'b'
```

Feeding this to `mypy` results with

```
error: Unsupported target for indexed assignment ("Collection[str]")
```

Putting a side that `mypy` inferred the wrong type for `d` (it is clearly not a collection of strings), adding a very basic explicit type for `d` fixes this:

```
d: dict = {
    ... # same as above
}
```

```
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

I find this very peculiar. `mypy` should definitely be able to infer that `d` is a dict without `d: dict`.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68803511/mypyerror-incompatible-types-in-assignment-expression-has-type-dictnothin/68807635#68807635

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`d` is not being inferred as a collection of strings. It is being inferred as a `dict`, but dicts take two type variables, one for the keys and one for the values. If we use `reveal_type`:

```
d = {
    'a': 'a',
    'b': {
        'c': 1
    }
}
reveal_type(d)
d['b']['d'] = 'b'
```

I get:

```
(py39) jarrivillaga-mbp16-2019:~ jarrivillaga$ mypy --version
mypy 0.910
(py39) jarrivillaga-mbp16-2019:~ jarrivillaga$ mypy scratch.py
scratch.py:7: note: Revealed type is "builtins.dict[builtins.str*, typing.Collection*[builtins.str]]"
scratch.py:8: error: Unsupported target for indexed assignment ("Collection[str]")
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

So, it is being inferred as: `builtins.dict[builtins.str*, typing.Collection*[builtins.str]]` which is a dict mapping strings to collections of strings. This is because for your dict, you have used `str` and `dict[str, int]` as values, and I can only surmise that `typing.Collection[str]` is the least broad type that encompasses `str` and `dict[str, str]` ha both. I'm not really sure how mypy is supposed to handle the inference of nested dict literals like yours.

Note, annotating with just `dict` means it is going to use `dict[Any, Any]`, which you probably *don't want*. You should try to give a more constrained type, but that depends on how you *intend* to use `d`.